# Change play icon in flowplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, flowplayer

I want to change the Play icon in flowplayer because when my video loads, the play button shows because of `autoplay:false` and the background is white so that's why play button is not shown properly. Here is my code:

```
<a href="http://localhost/project/videos/ydraw_vip_video.mp4" id="player"></a>
<script src="http://localhost/project/js/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.5.js"></script>
<script> 
flowplayer("player", "http://localhost/project/js/flowplayer-3.2.5.swf", {
    // a clip object
    clip: {         
        autoPlay: false,
        autoBuffering: true,
    },
    play: {
        url: 'http://localhost/project/img/play_button_flowplayer.png',
        width: 84,
        height: 84
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct way to display your own play icon.  The icon can be either `JPG`, `PNG` or `SWF`.

**Taken from flowplayer docs**

```
// default settings for the play button
play: {
    // relative path to the play button, this can be a JPG, PNG or SWF
    // file. NOTE: the button can only be changed in the commercial
    // versions
    url: 'play.swf',

    // all display properties, except the z-index, can be modified in
    // all versions
    opacity: 0.8,

    // label text; by default there is no text
    label: null,

    // label text at end of video clip
    replayLabel: 'Play again',

    // progress indicator - this is shown while video is being
    // loaded. it is always in the same place as the play button.

    // how fast progress indicator fades out after video is loaded
    fadeSpeed: 500,

    // how fast buffering animation rotates
    rotateSpeed: 50
}
```

For more details please see the flowplayer [branding docs](http://flash.flowplayer.org/documentation/skinning/branding.html)